# Why am I getting this error in my Android app? "emulator: ERROR: unexpected qemud char. channel close"

Tags: android

Whenever I try to launch an Android app it will cause this error:

> emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.hellos.ArithmaticCalculatorActivity activity launch'!

And after some time it will show this error:

> "emulator: ERROR: unexpected qemud char. channel close"

How might I resolve this?

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/msg/dd12248b7ec5a078

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is a known emulator bug. Do you happen to be running Ubuntu?

Try deleting and recreating your AVD. If you're still having problems, try the following:

1. Try launching in several ways: by starting the AVD first from your
   list of AVDs, by right-clicking the project in your workspace, etc.
2. Click on Window-->Show View-->Other-->Devies, and click on the
   launched device, highlighting it. There is a known issue that
   sometimes robs your AVD of focus unless you do this.

Answer (score 2):

That is a known emulator bug. Do you happen to be running Ubuntu?

Try deleting and recreating your AVD. If you're still having problems, try the following:

1. Try launching in several ways: by starting the AVD first from your list of AVDs, by right-clicking the project in your workspace, etc.
2. Click on Window-->Show View-->Other-->Devies, and click on the launched device, highlighting it. There is a known issue that sometimes robs your AVD of focus unless you do this.

Good luck!

--Avram

Comment: the error is removed thanks, i do not know how it happens but i just made the program again. and create a new avd

Comment: Do you happen to be running Ubuntu? what this i use windows

Comment: Hi Hassan, yeah, the AVD can sometimes be fickle. Ubuntu is a popular linux distro. I asked if you were using it because there are some known emulator bugs under ubuntu that ressemble the problems you were experiencing. Nine times out of ten, though, it's a loss of focus issue that can be solved by following #2 in my post above.

Comment: thanks avram a lot. i am very thankfull for this wonderful knowledge u share with me